# SQL - Read XML node value from attribute name

Tags: sql, xml

I have a column that contains an XML like this:

```
<metadata>
   <meta id="TypeX" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>3</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
   <meta id="TypeY" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>5</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
</metadata>
```

and I need to query it by meta Tag Attribute 'id'.

I need to have foreach 'meta' tag his id and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have something that should help:

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = '<metadata>
   <meta id="TypeX" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>3</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
   <meta id="TypeY" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>5</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
</metadata>'

select C.value('(./@id)', 'varchar(5)') AS [Meta ID]
     , C.value('(./values/value)[1]', 'tinyint') AS [Value]
from @xml.nodes('/metadata/meta') AS T(C)
```

Moreover, it could be useful for you to get familiar with XQueries :)

You can change data type in `select` statement from `varchar(5)` to some bigger `varchar` or from `tinyint` to some "bigger" type, if you need to.

Comment: Working answer, just some hints: If there are more `<value>` nodes below `<values>` (it looks like this...), you will read the first one only.  Secondly, especially with bigger XMLs, it is not performant to read the whole lot into a derived table, just to do the filtering externally.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML is big, it will lead to a bad performance, if you first shred the whole thing, just to filter it afterwards. It is better to include your filter as *predicate* into your `XQuery`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<metadata>
   <meta id="TypeX" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>3</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
   <meta id="TypeY" valuetype="xs:string">
      <values>
         <value>5</value>
         <value>6</value>
      </values>
   </meta>
</metadata>';
```

--This is the variable holding the id's value

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10)='TypeX';
```

--This `SELECT` reads the first `<value>` within `<values>` as *one-liner*:

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/metadata/meta[@id=sql:variable("@id")]/values/value/text())[1]','int');
```

--Change the filter-variable

```
SET @id='TypeY'
```

--This query will use `.nodes()` to get all `<value>` nodes within `<values>` (if there are more of them)

```
SELECT v.value('text()[1]','int')
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/metadata/meta[@id=sql:variable("@id")]/values/value') AS A(v);
```

One more hint: If you are sure, that there is only one entry per `@id`, you might extend the predicate to `[@id=sql:variable("@id")][1]`. This will prevent the engine to continue searching for nodes with this id.